# new mysqli vs mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysqli

What is difference between the new `mysqli` and `mysqli_connect`?
I know that executing a query is different;

for example: `mysqli->query()` and `mysqli_query()`

Why are there two different types, what is the need for the difference?

Comment: No it isn't, I tried to google it, but I thought that experience of people here could help me better and give me straight information about it

Answer (score 61, accepted):

One is for Procedural style programming and other is for OOP style programming. Both serve the same purpose; `Open a new connection to the MySQL server`

**OOP Style usage**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

**Procedural Style usage**

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Reference: [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: The PHP manual isn't even very clear on the implications of using either...

Comment: what's the best practice?  recreate the connection after each query? or allow the connection to persist?

Answer (score 14):

Right on @Hanky Panky. I'd also add to that the PHP docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

> Note:
>
> OO syntax only: If a connection fails an object is still returned. To
>   check if the connection failed then use either the
>   mysqli_connect_error() function or the mysqli->connect_error property
>   as in the preceding examples.

So error handling is just one difference.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a subtle but interesting difference between the two.

If you encounter a connection error with `mysqli_connect` (like `$connection = mysqli_connect()`), no mysql info will be returned to the $connection variable.  As such, you will not be able to identify the error with `myqli_errno($connection)`.

However if you encounter a connection error using new mysqli (like `$connection = new mysqli()`), the mysql info WILL be returned and you can check the error with `$connection->connect_errno`.

Knowing this, I'd opt for new mysqli.

Oops... Just saw answer from Rick Buczynski and realized after posting that I'm restating what he said, but his reply is more informative.

Comment: Your answer is a little bit wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439