# Have php7 working however when I try to make a mysqli object, "Class 'mysqli' is not found"

Tags: php, mysqli

I have php7 installed and working

I'm using the Built-in HTTP server

Uncommented `"extension_dir="C:\php\ext"` and `extension="php_mysqli.dll"` in the php.ini files development and production (did production too just to be safe)

When I used the `phpinfo()` method, I found that it says "Loaded Configuration file: none"

I've installed php7 therefore mysqli is supposed to already be installed. Looking online I found that you have to edit the php.ini file (mentioned how I did so in bullet points above) however when I run:

```php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Users\Calvin\try\learningMySQL.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Calvin\try\learningMySQL.php on line 17

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you reboot the webserver (apache) after making changes to your ini file?

Comment: I cancelled the server using Ctrl-C from the command line and started the local host up again. I'm just using the default HTTP server which comes with php. Is Apache the default which comes with php, or is it installed separately?

Comment: Just checked and it's the IIS server I have installed

Comment: Maybe this resource may be of help then; http://www.artfulsoftware.com/php_mysql_win.html

Answer (score -3):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";

$con = mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
```

Comment: I doubt this would work because `mysqli` and `mysqli_connect` are from the same package. Give this a quick read; [Difference between mysqli and mysqli_connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707696/new-mysqli-vs-mysqli-connect)

Comment: `mysqli` also work `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

Comment: Brother, his problem is that `mysqli` is not registed as a module, so I don't think it would. `new mysqli` is what he has already :)